# session variable not available in global before(:each, :type => :controller)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

I'm refactoring some specs, in controller specs I have a `before(:each)` which sets up things required in the session, wanted to avoid duplication and put the initial setup global for each controller spec

my before filter is...

```
config.before(:each, :type => :controller) do

  #... 

  session[:current_user] = @user
  session[:instance] = @instance

  #...

end
```

`@user` and `@instance` are also set in the `before(:each)`
i've just hidden them for readability here

I get the following error when running the controller tests

```
undefined method `session' for nil:NilClass
```

I would expect the global before callbacks to have the same things as the ones in the individual tests but I guess maybe they are loaded before the rails environment has been initialised?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `controller.stub!(:session, { :current_user => @user, :instance => @instance })`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more to do with Ruby and blocks (which are closures).

The block passed to `before` is bound to the context in which it is created, and `session` is not available in that context.